# System.Data.Odbc support of SQL Server datetime2, time, date, datetimeoffset types

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc

According to [ODBC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements), ODBC supports the SQL 2008+ types like `datetime2`, `date`, `time` and `datetimeoffset`.

But I am unable to use them with .Net `System.Data.Odbc` [connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection) and [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbccommand), excepted `Date`. They look unsupported by this ODBC client, although I have the "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" and its "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" driver:

- Trying to read a `Time` column with a `System.Data.Odbc` reader `GetValue`
  yields:

  ```
  System.ArgumentException : Unknown SQL type - SS_TIME_EX.
     at System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap.FromSqlType(SQL_TYPE sqltype)
     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)
     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
  ```
- Trying to read a `Time` column with a `System.Data.Odbc` reader `GetTime` cuts fractional seconds.
- Trying to set a `Time` parameter on an `OdbcCommand` cuts its fractional seconds.
- Trying to set a `DateTime2` parameter on an `OdbcCommand` yields:

  ```
  System.ArgumentException : No mapping exists from DbType DateTime2 to a known
  OdbcType.
     at System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap.FromDbType(DbType dbType)
     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter.set_DbType(DbType value)
  ```
- Setting a `DateTimeOffset` parameter yields the same error with just the db-type name accordingly changed.
- Trying to read a `DateTimeOffset` column with a `System.Data.Odbc` reader `GetValue`
  yields:

  ```
  System.ArgumentException : Unknown SQL type - -155.
     at System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap.FromSqlType(SQL_TYPE sqltype)
     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)
     at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
  ```
- Trying to read a `DateTimeOffset` column with a `System.Data.Odbc` reader `GetDateTime` cuts offset but preserves fractional seconds (all 7 digits).
- Checking [`OdbcType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbctype) enumeration, it does not have types for `datetimeoffset` or `datetime2`.
- Trying to dodge the trouble for `datetime2` by using `DbType.DateTime` instead for parameter:

  - Requires to set the parameter scale, otherwise fails with:

    ```
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException : ERROR [22008]
    [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Datetime field overflow.
    Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ```
  - When setting the parameter scale to 7, cuts fractional milliseconds even if the column in database is `datetime2`. This gives the one millisecond precision (compared to SQL Server `datetime` ten thirds of ms precision), but `datetime2` can go down to 100ns. Catching the query with SQL Server Profiler, we can see this:

    ```
    exec sp_executesql N'select count(*) from Types2008 where [DateTime2] = @P1',
    N'@P1 datetime2','2017-10-26 20:01:55.1630000'
    ```

    So the value is `datetime2` typed but has its fractional milliseconds zeroed out (yes my original value was not having them already zeroed).

    By the way this `datetime2` typing causes issues when the underlying table column is `datetime` instead, because it occurs in this case too. It causes `where` equality conditions to fail matching on two thirds of `datetime` values. Those ending with `3` or `7` milliseconds are not considered equal to the "same" value when typed `datetime2` with four trailing zero. Only those ending with 0 millisecond match.

Is `System.Data.Odbc` just quite lagging behind ODBC support of SQL Server types? Or is there any settings/code to adjust for having it supporting those types?

Those results were obtained with .Net Framework 4.7.1, a SQL Server Express 2016, and as connection string:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=.\sql_express;
Database=test;
Trusted_Connection=yes;
Mars_Connection=yes;
```

Troubles reproduced too with .Net Core 2.0 using System.Data.Odbc 4.5.0-preview1-25829-02 from MyGet.

Here is a complete [gist](https://gist.github.com/fredericDelaporte/e1563b1510ce31a01e7d9dc9e9387e6d).

Comment: I have additionally reported this for .Net Framework [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3143192) and for .Net Core [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24953). It now looks to me as a bug.

Comment: Re-reported for .Net Framework [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/281326/systemdataodbc-support-of-sql-server-datetime2-tim.html), since Microsoft Connect is retired.